# Internal structure of jagged array in .NET

Tags: .net, arrays, memory, clr, jagged-arrays

I created simple jagged array:

```
int[][] a = new int[2][];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    a[i] = new int[3];
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        a[i][j] = i * 3 + j;
}
```

After that I started debugging my application and looked to this array sturcture in memory (x86):

```
0x03022478           0  // SyncBlockIndex (a)
0x0302247C  0x61B8D5BC  // TypeHandle (a)
0x03022480           2  // a.Length
0x03022484  0x617A4C8A  // ???
0x03022488  0x03022494  // a[0]
0x0302248C  0x030224AC  // a[1]
0x03022490           0  // SyncBlockIndex (a[0])
0x03022494  0x61B9C448  // TypeHandle (a[0])
0x03022498           3  // a[0].Length
0x0302249C           0  // a[0][0]
0x030224A0           1  // a[0][1]
0x030224A4           2  // a[0][2]
0x030224A8           0  // SyncBlockIndex (a[1])
0x030224AC  0x61B9C448  // TypeHandle (a[1])
0x030224B0           3  // a[1].Length
0x030224B4           3  // a[1][0]
0x030224B8           4  // a[1][1]
0x030224BC           5  // a[1][2]
```

I understand almost all the data: SyncBlockIndexes, TypeHandles, Lengths, Elements. But I can't understand only one line:

```
0x03022484  0x617A4C8A  // ???
```

What it is?

**Update 1:**

I tried resolve this address value with different [SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) command:

```
!DumpArray 0x617A4C8A
<Note: this object has an invalid CLASS field>
Invalid object

!DumpAssembly 0x617A4C8A
Fail to fill Assembly

!DumpClass 0x617A4C8A
Invalid EEClass address

!DumpDomain 0x617A4C8A
Fail to fill AppDomain

!DumpMD 0x617A4C8A
617a4c8a is not a MethodDesc

!DumpMT 0x617A4C8A  
617a4c8a is not a MethodTable

!DumpObj 0x617A4C8A 
<Note: this object has an invalid CLASS field>
Invalid object    

!DumpSig 0x617A4C8A
!DumpSig <sigaddr> <moduleaddr>
```

**Update 2:**

In array of references types this DWORD should mean address of array element MethodTable. For example, for `object[10]` this DWORD is address of MethodTable for `System.Object`. But in the case of `int[][]` this DWORD is not valid MethodTable address (I use SOS-command DumpMT for checking it).

Comment: Is this word also present in `new object[10]`? It might have to do with the fact that an int[][] contains references while a int[] contains primitives.

Comment: @usr, yes, object[10] contains it strange data too. But what it is?

Comment: Try disassembling what happens when you execute `((object[])(new Stream[10]))[8] = "x"`. Maybe the mysterious word is used for fast runtime type testing for array stores. Maybe it is the element type or points to a function capable of doing the type test. The code shown will fail at runtime.

Comment: It looks like this value is present for `T[]` where `T` is a reference type and it is shared between arrays of the same type.

Comment: @usr, I did it, but I did not see the use of these data. CLR can resolve element type from the TypeHandle.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen, I agree with you, a reference type of principle. But why do we need these auxiliary data?

Comment: Try determining its type. Try interpreting it as a type handle, method handle or function pointer. What data is at this location?

Comment: @usr, I tried resolve it address with all of the sos commands (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx): DumpArray, DumpAssebly, DumpClass, DumpDomain, DumpMD, DumpMT, DumpObj, DumpSig. But none of these methods gave results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the SSCLI source code (`\sscli20_20060311\sscli20\clr\src\vm\object.h`):

```
// ArrayBase encapuslates all of these details.  In theory you should never
// have to peek inside this abstraction
class ArrayBase : public Object
{
    ...
    // This MUST be the first field, so that it directly follows Object.  This is because
    // Object::GetSize() looks at m_NumComponents even though it may not be an array (the
    // values is shifted out if not an array, so it's ok). 
    DWORD       m_NumComponents;
    ...
    // What comes after this conceputally is:
    // TypeHandle elementType;        Only present if the method table is shared among many types (arrays of pointers)
    // INT32      bounds[rank];       The bounds are only present for Multidimensional arrays   
    // INT32      lowerBounds[rank];  Valid indexes are lowerBounds[i] <= index[i] < lowerBounds[i] + bounds[i]
```

The extra word you are seeing should be the `TypeHandle elementType`:

> Only present if the method table is shared among many types (arrays of pointers)

`\sscli20_20060311\sscli20\clr\src\vm\typehandle.h:`

```
// At the present time a TypeHandle can point at two possible things
//
//      1) A MethodTable    (Intrinsics, Classes, Value Types and their instantiations)
//      2) A TypeDesc       (all other cases: arrays, byrefs, pointer types, function pointers, generic type variables)
```

`int[][]` is array of `int[]`, TypeHandle of `int[]` is TypeDesc. So, strange data is TypeHandle, but it can't resolved by !DumpMT because it's not a MethodTable.

The SSCLI is of course not the real Microsoft CLR implementation, but I understand it is a stripped down version of the 2.0 CLR.

Comment: Thanks! I agree with your answer (see my Update 2): it's work for single array of references type. But why I can't resolve this DWORD with !DumpMT for int[][]?

Comment: @DreamWalker maybe `!DumpMT` isn't able to to process the type handle for `int[]`? (Which is what I think should be at the address.)

Comment: @svick, 0x61B9C448 in my code example is address of MethodTable for int[]. It value used as TypeHandle for a[0] and a[1].

Comment: Reading through this right now: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx Notable: "TypeHandle, which is contained in the ObjectInstance, points to an offset from the beginning of the MethodTable. This offset is 12 bytes by default and contains GC information which we will not discuss here.". So try plus and minus 12 bytes as offset with DumpMT. Also, compare with `typeof(int[]).RuntimeTypeHandle` which should be the same value.

Comment: @usr, 1. This offset used for GCInfo (look to Figure 9 in article), DumpMT should resolve MethodTable from pointer to Flags. 2. In my example target MethodTable pointer is 0x61B9C448 (this address resolving with DumpMT) and 0x617A4C8A (this is my strange data); different is much greater than 12 byte. 3. It's so strange for me, but typeof(int[]).TypeHandle.Value equal to 0x617A4C8A.

Comment: @usr, I update your answer, information about TypeDesc was added.